# Adding JCheckBox Array to JPanel in Netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, auto-generate, jcheckbox

I've been trying to add an array of `JCheckBoxes` to a `JPanel` in Netbeans that has been automatically generated by the `Netbeans GUI`, when I create an array of the `JCheckBoxes` and then try to add them to the `JPanel` using `JPanel.add(jCheckboxArray[x])` , the program compiles ok but they don't appear.

I've created an array like so:

```
// custom private member variables
private javax.swing.JCheckBox[] jCheckboxArray;
//

int CheckBoxNumber = 5;
jCheckboxArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[CheckBoxNumber];
for(int x = 0; x < CheckBoxNumber ; x++) {
    jCheckboxArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckboxArray[x].setText("CheckBox " + x);
}
```

I've tried setting viable but no result, and all the examples online appear to make a reference to adding the `JPanel` to a `JFrame` however no `JFrame` exists in the auto-generated code probably because the auto generated class extends `javax.swing.JFrame`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the entire code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.ArduinoGUI;

/**
 *
 * @author EEE
 */
public class ArduinoGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form ArduinoGUI
 */
public ArduinoGUI() {
    initCustomComponents();
    initComponents();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox2 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox3 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox4 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox5 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Outputs"));
    jPanel1.setName("Outputs"); // NOI18N

    jCheckBox1.setText("jCheckBox1");

    jCheckBox2.setText("jCheckBox2");

    jCheckBox3.setText("jCheckBox3");

    jCheckBox4.setText("jCheckBox4");

    jCheckBox5.setText("jCheckBox5");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox5))
                .addComponent(jCheckBox2)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox3)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox4))
            .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox5))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jCheckBox2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jCheckBox3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jCheckBox4)
            .addGap(0, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("PinState"));

    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
    jRadioButton1.setText("Input");
    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
    jRadioButton2.setText("Output");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(8, 8, 8)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
            .addContainerGap(67, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Generated Boxes"));

    int CheckBoxNumber = 5;
    jCheckboxArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[CheckBoxNumber];

    for(int x = 0; x < CheckBoxNumber ; x++) {
        jCheckboxArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.print(jCheckboxArray[x].getText());
        jCheckboxArray[x].setText("CheckBox " + x);
        System.out.print(jCheckboxArray[x].getText());

        jPanel3.add(jCheckboxArray[x]);

    }

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 175, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ArduinoGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox2;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox3;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox4;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
// End of variables declaration

private javax.swing.JCheckBox[] jCheckboxArray;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox6;



private void initCustomComponents() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    // create checkbox array



}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried putting `setContentPane(yourJPanel);` in you're code? That should fix it.

Comment: When I add setContentPane(jPanel3); At runtime I get the error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Comment: I edited and added the entire code, it is as I'm just trying things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have given the example



 public static void main(String args[]) {
            String title = (args.length == 0 ? "CheckBox Sample" : args[0]);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test");
            panel.setBorder(border);

            javax.swing.JCheckBox[] jCheckboxArray;
            //

            int CheckBoxNumber = 5;
            jCheckboxArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[CheckBoxNumber];
            for(int x = 0; x < CheckBoxNumber ; x++) {
                jCheckboxArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
                jCheckboxArray[x].setText("CheckBox " + x);
                panel.add(jCheckboxArray[x]);
            }


            Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           // contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setSize(300, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
          }
```

Comment: I tried adding this and although it still compiles and runs without errors, the checkboxes do not show up in the jPanel

Comment: Thanks, your code works but I do not understand why my code does not work. I think the Netbeans Auto-generated code is over-riding the checkbox display in jPanel3 do you know what the problem in that code is ?

Comment: I think there is a problem in jPanel3Layout.just comment //jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);

Comment: @Zac Biswajit's code used a `GridLayout` instead of `GroupLayout`. That means you (or Netbeans) don't have to mess around with horizontal layouts, vertical layouts, etc. Also in your code, the layout for `jpanel3`was set _after_ you added your checkboxes (which is why the checkboxes wouldn't show - the layout had been "reset").

Comment: I have found in Netbeans the answer is to right click the jPanel in the GUI builder -> Set Layout -> "Anything but Free Design" ie Gridbox or Freeflow both work. The custom checkbox array code is included in the autogenerated code using the same process (right click jPanel -> Customize code).